# Is there a function finding common time-steps?

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to identify activities performed on the same place and with the same person for id during time t. The variable `wher` denotes time steps and records where the activities take place at time t. The with parameter records the with who the activity was performed at time t. I would like to know the duration or total number of occurrences of the activities that were performed at the same place and with the same person during time t based on id and pnum. Uncommon activities and activities performed at a different places with the different people I replaced with 0.

Input

```
id     pnum     t1  t2  t3  t4  wher1 wher2 wher3 wher4 wit1 wit2 wit3 wit4  
12       1      12  12  12  12  1        1   1     4     8     9    4    0  
12       2      10  13  12  12  3        1   1     5     6     5    4    1
12       3      10  13  12  12  3        1   1     5     6     5    4    1
```

Output:

```
id  t1  t2  t3  t4 Occurance number 
12   0   0  12  0   3
```

Sample data:

```
 df<-structure(list(id = c(12, 12, 12), pnum = c(1, 2, 3), t1 = c(12, 10, 10), t2 = c(12, 13,13), t3 = c(12, 12,12), t4 = c(12, 12, 12), wher1 = c(1, 3, 3), 
wher2 = c(1,1,1), 
wher3= c(1, 1, 1), wher4 = c(4, 5,5), wit1 = c(8, 6,6), wit2 = c(9,5,5), wit3 = c(4,4,4), wit4 = c(0, 1,1)),  row.names = c(NA,3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @akrun thanks uncommon means for example at times step t4 even though there are common activities these activities are performed at different places (4 and 5 and 5) and with different persons (0-1-1). Therefore is uncommon. Common is t3 were there are common activities, where has common elements and wit3 has common elements as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We reshape the dataset to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` by specifying the `names_sep` to split between the lowercase letter and a digit in the column names, then grouped by 'id', 'grp', `summarise` `if` the `n_distinct` of 't' and 'wher' column is 1, then return the `first` element of 't' or `else` 0, and reshape back to 'wide' format after creating the number of 'Occurance' by counting the number of 0's

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = t1:wit4, names_to = c(".value", "grp"), 
    names_sep = "(?<=[a-z])(?=[1-9])") %>% 
   group_by(id, grp) %>% 
   summarise(n = if(n_distinct(t) == 1 & n_distinct(wher)== 1) 
             first(t) else 0) %>%
   mutate(Occurance = sum(n == 0), grp = str_c('t', grp)) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = n)
# A tibble: 1 x 6
# Groups:   id [1]
#    id Occurance    t1    t2    t3    t4
#  <dbl>     <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    12         3     0     0    12     0
```